# How to return from within Python main function try statement?

Tags: python, azure-functions

Fairly new to Python, still trying to get my code structures straight. Having trouble "leaving" (not the right word) this Azure Function after hitting a certain step in the `try:` block.

Feels like wrapping everything in one big `try` `except` is the issue.

**What are some ways to bail out of the `try` block at different points?**

**Example:**

```
import os
import json
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from datetime import datetime, date
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

from ..utils import blob_storage_helpers
from ..utils import table_storage_helpers
from ..utils import aws_s3_helpers


def main(msg: func.QueueMessage):

    try:
        
        # Parse EventGrid message from QueueMessage body
        
        event_grid_msg_json = json.loads(msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
        blob_url = event_grid_msg_json['data']['blobUrl']
        
        logging.info(f'##### Environment: {os.environ["ENVIRONMENT"]}, Version: {os.environ["VERSION"]}')
        logging.info(f'##### Processing Queue Storage message: {event_grid_msg_json}')


        # Setup initial entity for TrackingTable

        entity = {
            'PartitionKey': date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d') + '_' + blob_url.split('/')[3],
            'RowKey': blob_url.split('/')[-1],
            'eg_msg': json.loads(event_grid_msg_json),
            'blob_name': blob_url.split('/')[-1],
            'blob_size': event_grid_msg_json['data']['contentLength'],
            'blob_type': blob_url.split('/')[3],
            'blob_url': blob_url,
            'source': blob_url.split('/')[3]
        }


        # Pull in App Settings
        
        config_table = os.environ['CONFIG_TABLE_NAME']
        tracking_table = os.environ['TRACKING_TABLE_NAME']
        ts_conn_string = os.environ['TABLE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING']
        s3_bucket = os.environ['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
        s3_access_key_id = os.environ['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
        s3_secret_access_key = os.environ['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
        

        # Create TableService to interact with TrackingTable
        
        table_service = table_storage_helpers.create_table_service(ts_conn_string)


        # Check if there is a destination for blobs in source container
        
        final_path = table_storage_helpers.get_final_path(table_service, config_table, entity['source'], entity['source'])


        # Update entity and write to TrackingTable     
        
        if final_path is None:
            entity.update({
                'dl_start_time': 'N/A', 
                'dl_end_time': 'N/A', 
                'destination': 'N/A', 
                'ul_start_time': 'N/A', 
                'ul_end_time': 'N/A',
                'status': 'Uploaded'})        
        else:
            entity.update({
                'status': 'Uploaded'})
        
        table_storage_helpers.update_tracking_table(table_service, tracking_table, entity)

        # RIGHT HERE I WANT TO GET OUT OF THE TRY BLOCK IF final_path IS NONE

        <code continues>
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Unable to process {e})
    return
```

**Edit 1:** Feels "ugly", but removed the outer `try/catch` then slapped a `return` if `final_path` is `None`.

- Reason it doesn't feel right is because I had to duplicate `table_storage_helpers.update_tracking_table`.

  [image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q40fT.png]

Comment: You can always `return` from a function if you want to exit back to the caller. You may be correct that wrapping everything in a single `try/except` block is a bad idea -- it's generally a bad idea to catch `Exception` (because this can mask real problems); you're better off catching *specific* exceptions that you expect your code to raise.

Comment: I didn't check your code but it has major issues that can make debugging very difficult first your try block is too long only put code that can result in an exception that you want to handle in a try block. Second don't catch ```Exception``` instead catch the specific exceptions that you **want** and **know** how to handle otherwise your program will fail silently.

Comment: Maybe it would help to explain why you have everything in a big try block. What happens if you just remove the try and except?

Comment: I'm still developing and learning so the big try block was to see what types of exceptions the various actions and services could/would throw. As part of learning, I will figure out *where* to find out about the exceptions (docs, general Python knowhow, etc.) that each piece of code could throw, then design the code around that.

Comment: See **Edit 1** in OP for initial changes made based on your (gracious!) input.

Comment: The best way to learn about the exceptions would be to let the program raise them normally, without catching them, so that you can read the error messages (traceback)! Unless your environment somehow doesn't report useful error messages and you need to track them using `logging` instead for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the code inside the try block in a function with return statement added wherever you want to exit and then call the function inside the try block